# Can I declare an autofilter as object?

Tags: vba

Hellow, is it possible to use?

```
dim x as Range
set x = Workbooks("main.xlsm").Worksheets("filter").Range("A1:Y100").AutoFilter field:=1, Criterial:="<>0"
```

I get an error saying that it expects end of instruccion and highlights field

[image]
[image]

Comment: Because you must use parentheses when you are storing a function's result into a variable? (Which is a general VBA rule, irrespective to whether the `AutoFilter` method specifically returns anything useful.)

Comment: `AutoFilter` doesn't return a Range object - seems like it only returns True/False.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Change `Criterial:="<>0"` to `Criteria1:="<>0"`  (replace the `l` for a `1`)      (I also added a picture with the English text "Compile error: Expected: end of statement")

Comment: You need to add parentheses around the arguments

Comment: @TimWilliams ir helps me to filter all cells with zeros and leave me only the rows with relevant data, sin all the other rows have zeros from a reference it’s very useful

Comment: Thanks @Luuk I will try it, always confuse me the >l with the >1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```vb
Dim x as Range

With Workbooks("main.xlsm").Worksheets("filter").Range("A1:Y100")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
    Set x = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
```

Just guessing what you want with `x` though.